# How to add value entered by a user , show the total and quit

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to add the value entered by the user, show the total after entering `q` to quit. I want to show the value before quitting the program but I always get this error

> Exception has occurred: Value Error invalid literal for integer ()
>   with base 10: 'q'"

```
while True: 
    seatvalue = int(input("please enter seat value (eg.30), 'q' to quit ")) 
    if seatvalue == 'q': 
        print [(seatvalue) + (seatvalue)] 
        print ("bye") 
        break
```

Comment: this is my code: while True:
    seatvalue = int(input("please enter seat value (eg.30), 'q' to quit "))
    if seatvalue == 'q':
        print [(seatvalue) + (seatvalue)]
        print ("bye")
        break

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of adding comments. Your code is barely readable in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is :

```
int(input("please enter seat value (eg.30), 'q' to quit ")
```

that line try to convert "q" to int , just check if is int before convert to int , you can achieve this with the "isnumeric" function.

```
value=0
while True: 
    given_value = input("please enter seat value (eg.30), 'q' to quit ")
    if given_value == 'q': 
        print(value)
        print("bye")
        break 
    if given_value.isnumeric():
        value += int(given_value)
```

Note that this code would omit all what's not a number or "q".

Comment: Nice "typo" in the comment :)